# How to display fields from the loop in two separate divs

Tags: loop, html

I'm making this website where i'm displaying things in two colums: on the left, a list of titles, when you click them, it expands a text and on the right it show the corresponding images.
To do so, I use a css grid.
Here is my code that I use to generate my blog posts and display the corresponding images.
My issue there is that `.four` is supposed to be on the left, that is correct, and `.five` should be on the left, but it's not since `.five` is generated under `.four` (left). How can I write this correctly so `.five` is not a child of `.four` and stays a child of my `.wrapper` but is keeping the `id()` order fine?

```
 <div class="wrapper-top">
    <div class="four">
    <?php
// the query
    $all_posts = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );

    if ( $all_posts->have_posts() ) :
        ?>

        <ul>
            <?php while ( $all_posts->have_posts() ) : $all_posts->the_post();  global $post;
                ?>

                <li class='sub-menu'> <a href='#' class="exposition"  data-id="<?php the_id();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> <ul>
                    <li><?php the_content(); ?>
                    <?php the_id();?>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="five"> 
        <?php $images = get_field('gallery');
        if( $images ): ?>
            <div class="slide-photos" id="<?php the_id();?>" data-id="<?php the_id();?>"> 
                <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
                    <div class="photos-ind"><img id="<?php the_id();?>" class="slide-photos" src="<?php echo esc_url($image['sizes']['thumbnail']); ?>" data-id="<?php the_id();?>"/></div>
                    <?php endforeach; ?></div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php else : ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would be just run the loop twice.

```
    <?php // set loop $args here so they're in once place ?>

    <div class="four">
        <?php // run the loop once with $args, output left side items ?>
    </div>
    <div class="five">
        <?php // run the loop again with $args, output right side items ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: you were right, it works!